# One seeder class is working but other is not working, do you know why?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-seeding

I have created two seeder classes 'UsersTableSeeder" and "Conferences TableSeeder". When the command "`php artisan db:seed`" is executed it appears:

Seeding: UsersTableSeeder

But the ConferenceTableSeeder don't work. Do you know why can be?

UsersTableSeeder:

```
class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        App\User::create([
            'name' => 'John',
            'email' => '',
            'password' => bcrypt('password')
        ]);
    }
}
```

ConferencesTableSeeder

```
class ConferencesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {

        App\Event::create([
            'name' => 'Test name',
            'description' => '',
            'date' => '2018-03-08 06:30:00',
            ...
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `ConferenceTableSeeder::class` to the `database\seeds\DatabaseSeeder.php` file

```
public function run()
{
     $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
     $this->call(ConferenceTableSeeder::class);
}
```

When you run `php artisan db:seed` it calls the `run` method in `DatabaseSeeder` class, which in turn calls the seeder files in there

The `UsersTableSeeder` is in there by default, that is why only that one ran

Answer (score 0):

Open this folder database\seeds\DatabaseSeeder.php and add the classname here to run all the seeders

write the below code to run seeder files  :

```
public function run()
{
     $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
     $this->call(ConferenceTableSeeder::class);
}
```

Note: you can also run a particular seeder file using the below code :

```
php artisan db:seed --class=ConferenceTableSeeder
```